# Kaltura report service doesn't provide data

Tags: rest, kaltura

I'm using the report service via the test API trying to get the same data I get via ***KMC>analytics>Top Content***. But I only get empty data tag.

```
<data>,,,,,</data>
```

Here is the KMC View with the data I want to reproduce using the test api:
[image]

Test API using *report* service with action *getTotal* and the following parameters:
[image]

Here is what I get:

```
<xml>
<result>
<objectType>KalturaReportTotal</objectType><header>count_plays,sum_time_viewed,avg_time_viewed,count_loads,load_play_ratio,avg_view_drop_off</header>
<data>,,,,,</data>
</result>
<executionTime>0.5377950668335</executionTime>
</xml>
```

I expect the data tag has some values like in the KMC View (45,09:22,00:12 and so on).

What am I missing ? Should I add/change some filter parameters ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fromDay and toDay should be in the following format YYYYMMDD
in your case fromDay - 20140602 and toDay – 20140625